# How to get shape in Excel using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am trying to get a shape on an Excel worksheet in VB.net. The same code I use in VBA doesn't work in VB.net. This works in VBA: `Set shp = wsStmt.Shapes("myShape")`

But in VB.net, this: `shp = wsStmt.Shapes("myShape")` gives a compiler error: `Interface 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shapes' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.`

So how do I get an Excel Shape from VB.net?

I tried googling this and can't find an answer. Presumably I need a different method of getting the shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Shapes.Item()` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840726%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Beautiful! Works nicely. Thanks